# Convert between scala class and Dynamic

Tags: scala.js

1. How do you convert from a scala class to Dynamic, so unmentioned javascript functions can be called?
2. How do you convert from Dynamic to a scala class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If by Scala class you mean a typed facade to JavaScript classes, i.e., a class/trait that extends `js.Object`, then you can convert simply with an `asInstanceOf`. For example:

```
val dateStatic = new js.Date
val dateDynamic = dateStatic.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic]
```

The other direction is the same:

```
val dateStaticAgain = dateDynamic.asInstanceOf[js.Date]
```

`.asInstanceOf[T]` is always a no-op (i.e., a hard cast) when `T` extends `js.Any`.

If, however, by Scala class you mean a proper Scala class (that is not a subtype of `js.Object`), then basically you can do the same thing. But only `@JSExport`'ed members will be visible from the `js.Dynamic` interface. For example:

```
class Foo(val x: Int) {
  def bar(): Int = x*2
  @JSExport
  def foobar(): Int = x+4
}

val foo = new Foo(5)
val fooDynamic = foo.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic]
println(fooDynamic.foobar()) // OK, prints 9
println(fooDynamic.bar())    // TypeError at runtime
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation. The conversions work.